# MongoDB query using WHERE and IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, sails-mongo

I need to fetch data from mongodb similer to the below sql query:

```
select * from ar_pages where (slug='ettarc' or id in ('1','2','3','4'))
```

Which uses one search condition and another with IN clause (fetch pages with specified slug and pages with list of ids)

I'm using **Node Sails** framework: I have tried below code: but it will not give the expected result

```
let listing = await Mymodel.find({
   $or: [{
      id: {
        $in: ['5cxxxx90xxxx2e23xxxxxxxx', '5cxxxx18xxxx2e81xxxxxxxx']
      }
   }, {
      user_id: 'xxxxxxxxx'
   }]
});
```

The above code returns below error on execution:

```
MongoError: $or must be an array
```

Mongo DB Document sample:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d286f93c04a685616627095"),
    "title" : "My First Page",
    "description" : "My First Page Contents",
    "user_id" : "5c80f410c1b9eb3d8fbf541c",
    "status" : "active",
    "createdAt" : 1562931091686.0,
    "updatedAt" : 1563528420160.0,
    "is_imported" : false,
    "background_img" : "",
    "background_color" : "",
    "logo" : "",
    "media_map" : null
}
```

Comment: Well, What's the question ..?

Comment: @nacho: I dont want someone to code me, just need a help, i tried too much for last 2 days i'm working on this, dont get the expected result,

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: Tried a lot, but dont get expected result, so the question is given this way. If u have an answer please suggest.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? Easier to build on that

Comment: @RakshithSm: but it returns the error: MongoError: $or must be an array

Comment: Please add an example document as well

Comment: done, added sample document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.ar_pages.find({

    "$or": [{
        "slug" : 'ettarc' 
    },{ "id": {"$in":  ['1','2','3','4']}
    }]
});
```

For Sails Framework use this:

```
db.ar_pages.find({
    or: [
       { 
          "slug" : 'ettarc' 
       }, {
          "id": {
             in:  ['1','2','3','4']
          }
       }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but return error:
MongoError: $or must be an array

Comment: Work for me when change $ sign. $ is not used in sails frame sork (sails mongo) for in and or operator. Instead of using $or and $in simply use or and in

Answer (score 2):

Your Query was trying to match `_id` without an `ObjectId()` wrap. You will need to wrap it up and then use it in your `$in`

```
db.ap_pages.find({
    $or: [{
        _id: {
            $in: [ObjectId('5d3595d9022a3de52f62ce79'), ObjectId('5d3595d9022a3de52f62ce7d')]
        }
    }, {
        user_id: '5c80f410c1b9eb3d8fbf541d'
    }]
});
```

To find that doc using Mongoose, you'd have to define _id in the schema for ap_pages as:

```
_id: { type: String }
```

and simply use it

```
db.ap_pages.find({
        $or: [{
            _id: {
                $in: ['5d3595d9022a3de52f62ce79', '5d3595d9022a3de52f62ce7d']
            }
        }, {
            user_id: '5c80f410c1b9eb3d8fbf541d'
        }]
    });
```

Comment: No, i 'm coding within a js file. when ObjectId is wraped, it shows: ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined

Comment: same response: MongoError: $or must be an array